# GCC thinks I'm running x86

Tags: android, gcc, 64-bit, cyanogenmod

I am trying to compile Cyanogenmod on Linux Mint 15. And receive the following error.

```
host StaticLib: libmincrypt (/home/benji/Source/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmincrypt_intermediates/libmincrypt.a)
ERROR: prebuilts/tools/gcc-sdk/../../gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/bin/x86_64-linux-ar only run on 64-bit linux
make: *** [/home/benji/Source/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmincrypt_intermediates/libmincrypt.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
# In case value of PACKAGES is empty.
```

-

```
benji@ultranoid ~/Source/prebuilts/tools/gcc-sdk $ ./gcc
ERROR: ./../../gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc only run on 64-bit linux
```

I can't figure out what is causing this. I am on a 64 bit install. Please advise.

```
benji@ultranoid ~/Source $ uname -p
x86_64
```

Comment: Did you try `-m` option?

Comment: Results in a similar error: http://pastebin.com/97ueHpmM

Comment: What was the build command you used?

Comment: `. build/envsetup.sh && brunch viva` I appended the `-m` option at the end.

Comment: so did you solved this error? i am also getting this/

Comment: I have not resolved this problem. I ended up installing Ubuntu to another partition and doing the compiling there. But I would still love to get this solved.

Comment: I have found a workaround. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Workaround**

Comment out lines 23-38 of prebuilts/tools/gcc-sdk/gcc

Example: http://pastebin.com/qH0BYcSF

Comment: yea commenting those check it worked for me...but i moved to ubuntu 10.04....its a best...

Comment: Didn't you by mistake comment out line 37 "Otherwise, choose 32-bit" ?

Comment: No, because I'm compiling in an x64 environment. Though you're right to a point. I should have left line 25 uncommented, but it still works fine with this workaround. So whatever.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-building/131h2qq409/why-does-the-build-process-think-im-running-32-bit), within Android build system the test for x32 vs x64 host is based on the output of `file -L "$SHELL" | grep -q "x86[_-]64"`. In other words it tests whether or not current shell is a 64 bit binary.

So a possible answer is : check out if value of environmental variable `$SHELL` is a valid path to a shell executable.

1. You may try to change shell with `chsh` or
2. create a link to your favorite shell so that $SHELL is satisfied. The latter did the trick for me - I've simply linked /bin/bash to where $SHELL pointed.

Comment: I had a problem - having `shell bash` in my `~/.screenrc` caused problems. Full path (`shell /bin/bash`) fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously `SHELL` points to login shell (which in my case is actually a symlink to another symlink that points to the actual binary) and not to the parent shell i.e. the shell the build script was invoked from.

Answer (score 0):

## use `uname -m` to check system.

#file -L "$SHELL" | grep -q "x86[_-]64"

#if [ $? != 0 ]; then

```
# $SHELL is not a 64-bit executable, so assume our userland is too.
```

# echo "ERROR: $MY_TOOL only run on 64-bit linux"

#  exit 1

#fi

#### changed to:

ARCH_OS=`uname -m | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

```
if [ "$ARCH_OS" != "x86_64" ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: $MY_TOOL only run on 64-bit linux from uname -m"
    exit 1
fi
```